# Apple OpenGL: Why is my drawing of a polygon with glVertexAttribPointer just folding a square?

Tags: opengl, polygon

Warning: trying to learn OpenGL ...

I have drawn a square with the following code.

```
    static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.33f, 
         0.5f, -0.33f,
        -0.5f,  0.33f, 
         0.5f,  0.33f,
    };

...

        glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
...

        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, squareVertices);
```

So naturally, I thought to add two more vertices and get a hexagon.  Instead, I have square that is folded like origami:

```
    static const GLfloat hexagonVertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.33f, 
        +0.0f, -0.66f, 
        +0.5f, -0.33f,
        +0.75f, +0.33f,
        -0.1f, +0.5f, 
        +0.25f, +0.33f,
    };

...

        glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, hexagonVertices);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);

...

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, hexagonVertices);
```

I have even tried changing the vertices to effect the shape.  I can morph the square into a irregular, four-sided polygon, and I can skew the "hexagon", but it is still just a folded piece of paper.

Can I do it this way?

What is the preferred alternate way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from sending a value of 3 in the second parameter of glVertexAttribPointer

This tells opengl to use 3 coordinates per vertex instead of the two that you want. Since you have 12 floats, this becomes 4 vertices, hence the square.

Edit: oh, and you need the first parameter of glVertexPointer to be 2 also.

Comment: Thanks - I thought I did originally keep the parameter to "2", but I was changing multiple things at once.  I now have a square, pentagon and hexagon.  I still don't quite get the order of the vertices - I keep thinking in terms of a path.  I must keep on reading ...